# Connect to internet with Sakis3g when modem establish network connection

Tags: usb, boot, modem

RP-beginner here,

**Background**

I'm using a shell script called Sakis3g to connect to internet and it works very well (It uses wvdial in the background and sets up a ppp-connection)

I want Sakis3g to run automatically and connect to a USB-modem (D-Link DWM-222) when the raspberry is booted to enable me to SSH into it from another computer. I know this can be done in multiply ways, such as placing the command in rc.local or init.d.

**The problem**

The thing is that the network I'm connecting to is not the public internet but hosted locally at a site. This network is not always available and the "sudo sakis3g connect" would fail.

**What I want**

I want to know that the modem has found the network before executing the "sudo sakis3g connect"

**Question**

What is the best way to go about this? Is there any way to trigger the command upon network identification? Or should I just keep running the command until it succeeds?

Comment: What is Sakis3g? The USB-modem is connected to a USB port of the RasPi? Where is the Sakis3g connected and how? Why do you need Sakis3g in addition to a modem?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sakis3g is a shell script that connects the USB-modem to 3G or 4G (LTE). So it is no hardware but just a script for connection. I want this script to run once the modem has found the network.

Comment: "*I want to know that the modem has found the network before executing the "sudo sakis3g connect"*" - This is done at startup. If then the network isn't available, you do not have a connection until you boot again, right?

Comment: Found a solution! :) See above

Comment: Congratulations on solving the problem yourself. Please consider adding it as an [answer to your own question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer); you can even [accept](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it later. That way, others having a similar problem can immediately see that an answer exists, which might help them solve their problem faster.

Comment: Marking the title with **SOLVED** is not the way this site works. I have corrected it. Please follow the suggestion of *AdminBee* in his comment above. Just cut and paste the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

In the source folder of Sakis3g there was a file that could be disassembled - modified - and compiled. The timeout threshold was set to 20sec in this file and by changing it to a higher number Sakio3g kept searching for the connection until the usb-modem found a network connection.

**Code**

```bsh
/urs/bin/sakis3g disassemble /tmp  
cd /tmp/sakis3g-0.2.0e/  
vim src/sakis3g # Search for network and find registration loop
./compile  
cp /tmp/sakis3g-0.2.0e/build/sakis3gz /usr/bin/sakis3g.
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take the liberty then to remove the "solution" part from your question, now that you have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.